# How to use these functions for a 'List' type

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I am trying to understand how to use the functions defined in the following Haskell code (available [here](http://d.hatena.ne.jp/Horiuchi_H/touch/searchdiary?word=*%5BHaskell%5D&of=5)) in Prelude.

```
module List
    where

data List a = Nil
            | Cons a (List a)

listLength :: List a -> Int
listLength Nil = 0
listLength (Cons x xs) = 1 + listLength xs

{-
listHead :: List a -> Maybe a
listHead Nil = Nothing
listHead (Cons x xs) = Just x

listTail :: List a -> Maybe (List a)
listTail Nil = Nothing
listTail (Cons x xs) = Just xs
-}
listHead :: List a -> a
listHead (Cons x xs) = x

listTail :: List a -> List a
listTail (Cons x xs) = xs

listFoldl :: (a -> b -> a) -> a -> List b -> a
listFoldl f c Nil = c
listFoldl f c (Cons x xs) = listFoldl f (f c x) xs

listFoldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> List a -> b
listFoldr f c Nil = c
listFoldr f c (Cons x xs) = f x (listFoldr f c xs)
```

I have loaded it using `ghci List.hs` command.

Then following is the way I am trying to use `listHead`.

```
*List> listHead (List 1:2:[])

<interactive>:7:11: Not in scope: data constructor `List'
```

Or like the following:

```
*List> listHead ('a':'b':[])

<interactive>:11:11:
    Couldn't match expected type `List a0' with actual type `[Char]'
    In the first argument of `listHead', namely `('a' : 'b' : [])'
    In the expression: listHead ('a' : 'b' : [])
    In an equation for `it': it = listHead ('a' : 'b' : [])
```

Could anyone please explain how to use this code in ghci? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are supposed to build your custom `List`s using the `Cons` and `Nil` *data constructors* that are defined by:

```
data List a = Nil
            | Cons a (List a)
```

The first error, `` Not in scope: data constructor `List' ``, happened because you can't use `List` to build values (`List` is a type constructor, and `List a` is a type). What you actually want is:

```
listHead (Cons 1 (Cons 2 Nil)))
```

The second error, `` Couldn't match expected type `List a0' with actual type `[Char]' ``, happened because you are trying to use the regular list constructors, `(:)` and `[]`, to build `List Char` values. You should use `Cons` instead of `(:)` and `Nil` instead of `[]`.

Answer (score 3):

The `:` operator and the `[]` construct are specific to Haskell's built-in list type, i.e. you can only use them to construct values of some type `[a]`. But the functions you have here don't deal with this standard list type, but with the locally defined `List` container. To construct such lists, you need to replace each `:` with `Cons` and each `[]` with `Nil`. It's complicated a bit by the fact that `Cons` is not an infix operator, so you first need to rewrite `a:b` as `(:) a b`. For example, the `[Int]` list `1:2:[]` becomes `(:) 1 ((:) 2 [])`, and that is equivalent to `Cons 1 (Cons 2 Nil)`.

Those custom-lists can then be fed to any of those functions.

```
*List> listHead $ Cons 1 (Cons 2 Nil)
1
```

Of course this is ugly, but that `List` type is only introduced for educational purposes. In practice, you would use the standard `[]` type, or use nicer constructors. For instance, you can define infix constructors like `:` yourself:

```
infixr 6 :&
data List' a = N | a :& List' a
```

With that you could just do

```
*List> list'Head $ 1 :& 2 :& N
```

Alternatively, you could make GHC accept the `[]` syntax for your custom list type:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedLists, TypeFamilies #-}

import GHC.Exts (IsList(..))

instance  IsList (List l) where
  type Item (List l) = l
  fromList [] = Nil
  fromList (a:l) = Cons a $ fromList l
```

And then

```
*List> listHead [1,2]
1
```